# crystal report get current amount based on the date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report in the following setup. e.g

GroupHeader

### Group #1 Name    |   CurrentValue    |       SumOfAmount (for each groupname)

```
GroupA                    0.00               45.00
GroupB                    0.00               79.00
GroupC                    0.00               150.00
```

The detailSection1 is empty.
In GroupA there are 3 Records if I display them on the detailsection1 . e.g

### GroupA

```
 AAA              5.00             2018/01/30
 ABC              20.00            2018/01/30
 BCC              20.00            2018/01/29
```

Now I would like to get the sum of current value based on the entered date (`?EndDate` parameter field): in this case `EndDate = 2018/01/30` and display it on the GroupHeader. e.g

### GroupName                |      CurrentValue          |      Sum

GroupA                   |     25.00                  |      45.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following formula and create a sum of it:

```
If {Table.DateColumn}={?EndDate} Then
    {Table.AmountColumn}
Else
    0
```

Comment: Thanks, @MatSnow : I was also able to get the currentValue using a date range and make a sum out of that.

Comment: Hi all, I encountered another error: Error in formula CurrentValue: IF {Table.DateCol} >= {?StartDate} and {Table.DateCol} <= {?EndDate} Then {Table.AmountColumn} Else 0. it says A string is requied here . this happens when {Table.DateCol} is null . how can I avoid the error.

Comment: @Nkhumisenikholophe You shouldn‘t ask new questions in comments. Better create a new question instead.